# Thread pool in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I write application in Java using ThreadPool. Firstly I create new ThreadPool:

```
private ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 20 );
```

Then I create some Runnable objects. After that I execute my ThreadPool from time to time passing him the same Runnable object:

```
threadExecutor.execute(serverRunnable);
```

I execute this ThreadPool every 20 seconds. My problem is that threadExecutor stops working for some 5 minutes. It just don't execute Runnable object. I notice that when I increase argument in:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 20 );
```

from 20 to e.g. 100 ThreadPool will work longer. Can anybody explain me why ThreadPool stop working?

Ps. I write this code in Android

Comment: Please post the code from your `serverRunnable` object.

Comment: Do your Runnable stop correctly? If they never end their `run()` method, your pool will be exhausted and `execute()` will lock waiting for one slot in the pool to be available.

Comment: Well I use serverRunnable for example. I pass many different Runnable to ThreadPoll and they all stops. Some of them do trivial work write something in log.

Comment: I think my run() stops correctly. I dont have in them while loop or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly if you want to schedule as task for execution every 20 seconds try to use  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instead : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

It seems your runnable does not terminate - in this way it will exceed the 20 threads after a fixed amount of time. If your runnable terminates normally - you will be able to use your executor infinitely long.